# Rails: Iterating over array of strings inside hash (flash error messages)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to iterate over the following:

```
flash = {"danger"=>["Password can't be blank", "Name can't be blank"]}
```

My code for iterating over these flash error messages is as follows:

```
  <% flash.each do |name, message| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name %>">
      <%= message %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Here is how I am setting flash (I changed it to allow multiple errors, so I think):

```
  flash[:danger] = []
  @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
    flash[:danger] << message
  end

  render :new
```

What I seem to get in return, instead of multiple div's with each error message separate, is the following (all within a div.alert alert-danger, which is correct):

["Password can't be blank", "Name can't be blank"]

I cannot seem to figure out how to simply iterate over each message individually. I need the key (danger) for my class, and the value (error message) to display in the div.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Why you are overriding the default `flash`?

Comment: try each_pair instead of each

Comment: @Pavan I'm new, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Read it https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html

Comment: My issue was that I wanted to be able to have multiple error messages in flash[:danger], so I created an array for the messages. Getting each error message to display properly has been challenging.

Comment: @Navin Thank you for trying to help. I received: undefined method `each_pair' for #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007f8c958c9b40>

Comment: instead of flash can u use some other variable name

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390778/best-practice-method-of-displaying-flash-messages

Comment: @Navin I think flash is the built in error reporting feature, but like I said, I'm new. I actually have it working fine for single errors, but I am trying to show numerous errors at once. If I leave it as is, I can only show one error at a time because setting flash is as follows: `flash[:danger] = "some warning"` so it overwrites if there are numerous errors, thus only letting me show the user one error at a time. So what I did is create an empty array, and push the error in as they come. I'll edit the original post to show it.

Comment: Interesting post @Navin. I tried it, I keep getting the same output (all errors in one array, instead of separate): ["Password can't be blank", "Name can't be blank"]

Comment: I think I must of messed it up when I changed how flash[:danger] was created. Perhaps I"m only limited to show one error at a time (of the same type, in this case, 'danger'). I'll keep tinkering around, but I may just have to settle for one error at a time.

Comment: only one key "danger" or multiple key u have?

Comment: I didn't see you changed your code, I tried the nested each and it did not seem to work. Perhaps I implemented it wrong - I will keep trying.

Comment: Yes only one key of "danger" @Navin. It is exactly as shown in my original post.

Comment: @Navin Thanks for all your help. I found this post, which basically says I can join the array and display it all at once. That should be fine. Thanks again. [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436443/flash-message-within-a-loop-will-not-display-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of what you have, you need:

```
<% flash.each do |name, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name %>">

  <% if Array === message %>
    <ul>
    <% message.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% else %>
    <%= message %>
  <% end %>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you want to clean this up a bit, you could set all your flash messages to be arrays and eliminate the conditional that way. Then you'd have:

```
<% flash.each do |name, messages| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name %>">

  <ul>
  <% messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

In this case, you'll end up with list items for even single messages, but you can use CSS to format them how you want them.